# Как правильно написать аналогичный хук wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, hook

У меня нет опыта в работе с вордпресс. Вот прям вообще нет никакого опыта.
Есть уже написанный Middleware на Laravel 8 - Скажите , как правильно написать hook для WordPress что бы заглушку он возвращал на все страницы сайта с тем же URL-ом что и запрос для всех кроме поисковых роботов с кодом ответа 200

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $referer = request()->headers->get('referer');
    $baseUrl = request()->headers->get('host');
    $ip = request()->ip();
    if (
        (new Agent)->robot() == 'Yandex' or(new Agent)->robot() == 'Ya'
        or $request->input('turbo') == 'true'
        or $referer == "https://yandex.ru/turbo/$baseUrl/s/"
        or $ip == '127.0.0.1') {

        return $next($request);
    }

    return response()->view('layouts.zaglushka');
}
```

Допустим вот так вот можно уже что то делать, другой вопрос - как выводить заглушку с кодом 200 - то есть заменять шаблон страниц на другой - как это сделать?

```
function redirect_zaglushka(){ 



if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "yandex")){
    echo ('yes');
  }
  else { 
    echo ('No');
  }
}
// привяжем функцию к хуку
add_action( 'my_hook', 'redirect_zaglushka' );
// выполним хук
do_action('my_hook');
```

Comment: Правильно - возвращать для людей тоже, что и для ПС. И насколько я понял невнятные хотелки это должна быть страница 404.

Comment: @SeVlad - во первых, что для вас "невнятные хотелки" ? У меня есть задача - и я не спрашиваю, что правильно для поисковых систем. А невнятные хотелки это не 404 страница - есть вопрос - вы вместо ответа задаете "идиотский" и "бессмысленный" вопрос. Есть страница "mypage.html" и для всех нужно ее показывать с кодом 200 по любому из доступных урлов на сайте - вот и все. Ваше мнение о том, что правильно, а что не правильно меня не интересует

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно Вам подойдет [template_redirect](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/template_redirect)

Answer (score 1):

Я повторил логику кода в вашем ответе, оформив её согласно принципам и стандартам кодирования WordPress.

```
<?php

/**
 * Show plug.
 */
function show_plug() {
    require 'plug/plug.php';
    die;
}

/**
 * Show site to search bots only, otherwise redirect to plug.
 */
function redirect_to_plug() {
    $agents = [
        'yandex',
        'googlebot',
        'bingbot',
        'duckduckbot',
        'slurp',
        'ia_archiver',
        'facebot',
        'facebookexternalhit',
        'konqueror',
        'exabot',
    ];

    $agent = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ?
        strtolower( filter_var( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) :
        '';

    if ( in_array( $agent, $agents, true ) ) {
        return;
    }

    show_plug();
}

/**
 * Template redirect action.
 */
function template_redirect_action() {
    $uri = isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ?
        filter_var( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) :
        '';

    $url_path = wp_parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_PATH );

    if ( '/mirror' !== $url_path ) {
        redirect_to_plug();
        return;
    }

    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( '/', 301 );
    }

    show_plug();
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_action' );
```

Это полный контент файла,который может быть использован как `mu-plugin` (обязательный к использованию плагин. Создайте папку `wp-content/mu-plugins`, если её нет, и поместите туда этот файл. В этой же папке создайте подпапку `plug` и поместите в неё файл `plug.php` с кодом вашей заглушки.

Код протестирован, работает.

Answer (score -1):

Ну кому может быть интересно мое решение (подозреваю что это костыль конечно) -> но я писал что в wordpress я ничего не понимаю - так что вот пожалуста!

1. Function.php -> активной темы

   ```
   function redirect_st(){
   if( strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "/visit-zerkalo")){
           $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
           if ( $detect->isMobile() or $detect->isTablet()) {
               header("Location: example.com", TRUE, 301);
           }
           else {
               require get_template_directory() .'/zaglushka.php'; die;
           }
   }
   else {
       return true;
   }
   }
   function redirect_zaglushka(){ 

   if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "yandex") 
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot")
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "bingbot")
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "duckduckbot")
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "slurp")
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "ia_archiver")
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "facebot")
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "facebookexternalhit")
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "konqueror")
       or strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "exabot")){
       return true;
   }
   else { 
       require get_template_directory() .'/zaglushka.php'; die;
   }
   }
   add_action('redirect_hook' , 'redirect_st');
   do_action('redirect_hook');
   // привяжем функцию к хуку
   add_action( 'my_hook', 'redirect_zaglushka' );
   // выполним хук
   do_action('my_hook');
   ```
2. wp-load.php -> absolute path

   ```
   require_once ABSPATH . 'Mobile_Detect.php';
   ```
3. файл заглушки добавляем в корень темы активной
4. на всякий случай я так же поключил файл класса Mobile_Detect.php в корневой индекс

Comment: `add_action` и `dp_action` подряд смысла имеют ровно ноль. То же самое, что просто вызвать функцию `redirect_st` или `redirect_zaglushka`. Детектирование устройств есть в ядре wp. Править ядро `wp-load.php` - последнее дело, при обновлении правки слетят.